# Msql Message Unknow column

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, routes, sequelize.js

Hi cannot understand im using sequalizer when i go insomnia i do post Comment and its work so another side that i need to check or commentGet its working when i press send i get Error: Failure when receiving data from the peer. Next i go to check my terminal and its says

```
code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
    errno: 1054,
    sqlState: '42S22',
    sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'PostId' in 'field list'",
    sql: "SELECT `id`, `commentBody`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `PostId` FROM `Comments` AS `Comments` WHERE `Comments`.`PostId` = '5';",
    parameters: undefined.
```

And onother thing that in my MySql database doesnt event creating PostId line..

models
Comments.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Comments = sequelize.define("Comments", {
    commentBody: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
  });

  return Comments;
};
```

Posts.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Posts = sequelize.define("Posts", {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    postText: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  });

  Posts.associate = (models) => {
    Posts.hasMany(models.Comments, {
      onDelete: "cascade",
      
    });
  };
  return Posts;
};
```

Routes

Comments.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { Comments } = require("../models");

router.get("/:postId", async (req, res) => {
  const postId = req.params.postId;
  const comments = await Comments.findAll({ where: { PostId: postId } });
  res.json(comments);
});

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const comment = req.body;
  await Comments.create(comment);
  res.json(comment);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Posts.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { Posts } = require("../models");

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const listOfPosts = await Posts.findAll();
  res.json(listOfPosts);
});

router.get("/byId/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const post = await Posts.findByPk(id);
  res.json(post);
});

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const post = req.body;
  await Posts.create(post);
  res.json(post);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please show model registration code along with associations registration. Also how did you create the table?

Comment: **await Comments.findAll({ where: { PostId: postId } ** clearly you are trying to use PostId.  Does this exist in the database ?

Comment: postId is working when i use POST comment from insomnia its working i make POST but when i try to GET comment example id5 į get error message same message where i writted top